# Como gerar apk assinado com chaves diferentes

Tags: android

Minha problema é o seguinte

Tenho um app no Google Play que subi há algum tempo.

Crie uma chave e suas respectivas senhas.

Agora fiz algumas melhorias e quando fui gerar o apk assinado não encontrei o arquivo onde tinha salvo a senha. Possuo apenas o arquivo .jk que usei para assinar a primeira versão.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma para que eu consiga subir uma nova versão do app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem como você descobrir sim, mas não é 100% de certeza que funcione.

Use essa ferramenta: [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki)

1 - Baixe o jar e coloque na mesma pasta da sua keystore, em seguida execute o segundo comando:

```
java -jar AndroidKeystoreBrute_v1.05.jar -m 3 -k sua-keystore.jks -d sua-lista-de-palavras.txt
```

Eu testei em uma keystore na qual havia botado duas palavras e mais 3 numeros como senha, sendo a primeira letra da senha com letra maiuscula.

Na minha lista de palavras eu apenas forneci as duas palavras que estavam na senha. A letra maiuscula para a primeira é adicionada automaticamente bem como os números. Na sua lista você coloca as palavras que acha que estariam na senha (caso acha que tenha uma data, coloque também)

Sua lista pode ficar assim:

```
primeiraPalavra
segundaPalavra
01032016
```

Eu recebi a seguinte resposta ao executar:

```
Got Password in 12 seconds
```

Bem como a senha e o alias que usei. Deixe executando e boa sorte!

Comment: Então, sei que coloquei uma senha aleatória (bati com a cabeça no teclado e o resultado foi como senha) neste caso, posso colocar apenas letras na minha lista de palavras? obrigado

Comment: Você pode, é você quem decide. Mas para descobrir sua senha pode demorar muito mais. Você pode tentar o método 1, que é na força bruta. Aí você não precisa fornecer nenhum tipo de lista. Mas acho bem improvável de você descobrir sua senha desse modo, ao menos não num tempo hábil.